# select JDatechooser from String Sql

Tags: java, swing, jdbc

when i select return book date from `JDateChooser` and click enter button..the return date is not display in the `JTable`.

```
private void jButton19ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                          
    try
    {
        ((JTextField)jDateChooser7.getDateEditor().getUiComponent()).getText();

        String sql="select * from borrowed_book_record where return_date='"+jDateChooser7.getDateFormatString()+"'";



        pst=conn.prepareStatement(sql);
        rs=pst.executeQuery();


        jTable4.setModel(DbUtils.resultSetToTableModel(rs));
        jTable4.setVisible(true);

    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,""+e,"Error",JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
    }

}
```

Comment: Can you share the code of `DBUtils`?

Answer (score 0):

without any example, i could only guess on the dateformat.
Check the dateformat of the datecomponent against the dateformat return by the sql query!